# How can I do it better to convert my code

Tags: ios, swift

I was told to translate the code from obj-c to swift. Unfortunately, I only studied Swift. Please help me with the translation.

Obj-c:

```
struct {
    unsigned int didDoneClicked : 1;
    unsigned int didCancelClicked : 1;
  } _delegateFlags;
```

That's what I did:

```
struct _delegateFlags {
didDoneClicked: Int = 1
didCancelClicked: Int = 1
}
```

I do not really understand what "unsigned". Tell me how to make it more correct

Comment: You can use `UInt` in swift

Comment: No leading underscores but uppercased struct names in Swift

Comment: @vadian Can you write the correct answer? I'm just a beginner

Comment: Can you show us how you plan on using this structure in your swift code? The original code is actually C. It's a struct with bit fields. Bit fields only occupy a single bit. Anyways, the question I have is can didDoneClicked and didCancelClicked both be one? Or can only one property have a value of one. This looks more like it should be an enum to me.

Comment: I updated my answer with OptionSet. But as Rob pointed out you should give details on what is this struct used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer types could be signed (with negative numbers as well as positive ones) or unsigned (only positive numbers). There is a lot of documentation on internet about integer types, you should read it.

Unsigned integer are usually used to store counters as they are always positive.

The equivalent in Swift for `unsigned int` is `UInt`.

The correct way is:

```
struct DelegateFlags {
  var didDoneClicked: UInt
  var didCancelClicked: UInt
}
```

Note that you should use the `var` keyword in Swift. Also if you want to match [Swift style guidelines](https://google.github.io/swift/) you should drop the underscore for an uppercased first letter.

---

## Note

This struct looks like a C bit field used to store boolean values in a memory efficient way, by storing the information on 1 bit instead of 8.

If you want to match the exact C memory pattern the Swift way is:

```
struct DelegateFlags: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: UInt

    static let didDoneClicked = DelegateFlags(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let didCancelClicked = DelegateFlags(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}
```

However if you need a simpler struct still more memory efficient than the 1st I presented, here is an alternative:

```
struct DelegateFlags {
  var didDoneClicked: Bool
  var didCancelClicked: Bool
}
```

The first struct is 16bytes, the second one is 8byte (can be made 1byte with `UInt8` though) and the last one is 2bytes. As the number of cases grow, the second one will be the most efficient (8 times less memory Thant the last one and 64x less than the first).

Comment: Right, but this isn't an answer. The original struct contains bit fields in the C programming language.

Comment: What do you mean? `UInt` is a fixed width integer, it also represents a bit field.

Comment: Honestly, what you have should suffice. I think the confusion on my part lies as to why the original struct contained bit fields. If you are familiar with C, bit fields only occupy a single bit.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean there I think, I'll update my answer.

Comment: In any case, I don't think you can provide a proper solution without getting more feedback from the OP.

Comment: @LouisLac var didDoneClicked: Bool - correctly, i check in my project, thanks bro <3